Django-filer. Sorting files in the admin panel
Is there any way to change the sorting of files in admin panel by download date? So that the most recently downloaded files are always at the top of the list.
I didn't find any suitable settings in the django-filer documentation
https://django-filer.readthedocs.io/

@admin.register(ExampleModel)
class ExampleModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'last_downloaded', 'owner','created_at')
    # With list_display we specify which files will be displayed in the admin panel
    ordering = ('-last_downloaded')
    # With ordering we set which column to sort by.
    # Here, the last_downloaded column will be sorted in descending order (-)


While this code might help the asker, it would be more helpful if you could add an explanation of how and why it works. This helps future readers understand the solution better.

Thank you for your feedback, I will be more careful.

Thanks for updating your answer, it makes much more sense now!
